# Deployment of blockchain demo app in Bluemix not possible

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm trying to deploy e.g the Car Lease demo application in Bluemix, but deployment doesn't seem to be possible once you will deploy in Bluemix.

I go to the section "Related links" here:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/index.html#gettingstartedtemplate
Click e.g. "IBM Car Lease Demo (Github)", and when clicking "Deploy to Bluemix" you are redirected to Bluemix. In Bluemix you are asked to create a (DevOps) toolchain including a "Delivery Pipeline" service (that doesn't exist more in the catalog). The "Deploy" button is de-active, and hence you are unable to deploy.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you note, the DevOps Delivery Pipeline service no longer exists. The Car Lease demo's "Deploy to Bluemix" button needs updating to leverage the Continuous Delivery service that replaced the DevOps service. You can manually create a [Continuous Delivery](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/continuous-delivery?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south&taxonomyNavigation=apps) service for your Bluemix org/account.

Once created, you can select the option to create a new pipeline from a template, and select the [Simple Cloud Foundry toolchain template](https://console.bluemix.net/devops/setup/deploy?repository=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fopen-toolchain%2Fsimple-toolchain&env_id=ibm:yp:us-south). Specify the Car Lease repository's address in the "Source repository URL:" field - https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/car-lease-demo. That should set you up with a pipeline.

I should note that the Blockchain services are being refreshed in the near term, and hence even this workaround will be short lived, until the team gets around to updating the Car Lease demo for Hyperledger Fabric v1.0.